# Applications of the Kuratowski closure-complement theorem

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, applications

I crossed with the Kuratowski closure-complement theorem while learning Munkres's Topology (Problem 21 in Section 17; Page 102, 2nd edition). The following description is from [B.J. Gardner and M. Jackson](http://nzjm.math.auckland.ac.nz/images/6/63/The_Kuratowski_Closure-Complement_Theorem.pdf).

> **The Kuratowski Closure-Complement Theorem:** If $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space and $A \subseteq X$ then at most 14 sets can be obtained from $A$ by taking closures and complements.

As stated in [B.J. Gardner and M. Jackson](http://nzjm.math.auckland.ac.nz/images/6/63/The_Kuratowski_Closure-Complement_Theorem.pdf), this remarkable theorem and related phenomena have been the concern of many authors. However, being not a researcher in Topology,

> **My Problem:** I would expect to see more interesting *applications* of the Kuratowski theorem in other fields, even in some non-mathematical fields (such as *computer science*).

I failed to find related literatures through googling.

Comment: A comprehensive bibliography through 2012 on this subject can be found at www.mathtransit.com.  References are listed in chronological order.

Comment: @mathematrucker Thanks. For me, however, the resources are still theories focusing on topology/algebra rather than applications in other fields. (I have just scanned through this list.)

Comment: Though not "applications", these two papers are close to computer science: [Complements and Transitive Closures](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X7290057X), [The Fast Skew-Closure Algorithm](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?rid=ensmat-001:1980:26::125).  This 1994 talk may actually qualify as suggesting an application, in a (very) non-mathematical field: [Topological Foundations of Cognitive Science](http://ontology.buffalo.edu/smith/articles/topo.html)